# Does 4.Ng5 in Two Knights Defense have a name?

Tags: opening, two-knights

Just like the title says, is there a name for the line starting with 4.Ng5 in 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 called?

Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Knights_Defense, does not give a name.

This Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKoZkrBWDbU refers to 4.Ng5 as *The Knight Attack*, but I searched for it and I don't see other references to *The Knight Attack*.

Also, often people refer to 4.Ng5 as Fried Liver attack, which I believe is incorrect, since Fried Liver attack arises later in the game, after 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5 Nxd5 6. Nxf7.

Comment: I would probably call it the Prussian game, although technically that might only apply to 4...d5 5.exd5 .
I am not sure if there's an explicit name for just 4.Ng5 .

Comment: I think the answer to this is just "No.", but that feels more like a comment. Lots of lines are just called by their defining move.

Comment: I think "Fegatello" is often used

Comment: @David: that's the name for the variation starting with 4..d5 5.exd5 Nxd5?! 6.Nxf7!?, Fegatello means Fried Liver.

Answer (score 2):

I think the name for `4. Ng5 is Knight Attack`. There isn't a specific name, because it leads to more specific openings, like the Fried Liver Attack, Polerio Defense `4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5 Na5` (trying to prevent the sacrifice), the Traxler Countergambit `4. Ng5 Bc5`, and more. It's just like how `1. e4 e5` is called the `open game`. There isn't a specific name for it, because it will lead to more specific opening.